# Best way to add a String in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

which is the best way to add formated string in jframe.
Previously I was trying to add jlabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display some text in a window, yes, adding a `JLabel` to your `JFrame` is fine.

Just create an instance of the font you want and assign it to the `JLabel` using [`setFont`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont(java.awt.Font)).

Here is a code samle (taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/javaawtFont.htm)):

```
Font font = new Font("Jokerman", Font.PLAIN, 35);
JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(textMessage);
textLabel.setFont(font);
```

Comment: @nicky: Use a java.util.Timer() and SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: Even more conveniently, a javax.swing.Timer action event handler executes on the event dispatch thread: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html